# hdfs : command not found

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

Here is how I configured the hadoop and Java environment variables.I installed hadoop . but when I execute the command #sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave.
hdfs :command not found.I have already uninstalled and reinstalled but the problem has not been solved.I have attached the output of the command .#hdfs namenode -format. here I reformatted the namenode.

```
[root@MASTER ~]# sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
sudo: hdfs: command not found

# JAVA VARIABLES
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin

# HADOOP VARIABLES
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
#export HADOOP_USER_NAME=$user
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"


  [root@MASTER ~]# hdfs namenode -format
21/06/22 20:20:02 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   user = root
STARTUP_MSG:   host = MASTER/192.168.1.5
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.8.1

STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_291
************************************************************/
21/06/22 20:20:02 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
21/06/22 20:20:03 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
21/06/22 20:20:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Formatting using clusterid: CID-1b107e40-11f9-4e20-8a4b-c966088e6eb9
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSEditLog: Edit logging is async:false
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: KeyProvider: null
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair: true
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Detailed lock hold time metrics enabled: false
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2021 Jun 22 20:20:06
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = root (auth:SIMPLE)
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occurring more than 10 times
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
21/06/22 20:20:06 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /hadoop/hdfs/namenode ? (Y or N) y
21/06/22 20:20:11 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-963069543-192.168.1.5-1624393211127
21/06/22 20:20:11 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /hadoop/hdfs/namenode has been successfully formatted.
21/06/22 20:20:11 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Saving image file /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
21/06/22 20:20:11 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Image file /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 321 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
21/06/22 20:20:11 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
21/06/22 20:20:11 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
21/06/22 20:20:11 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at MASTER/192.168.1.5
************************************************************/
```

Comment: 1) Did you format the namenode already 2) You should provide the namenode process logs to show why it is in safemode.

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, yes I format namenode already. 2) I will  do a post with logs now.

Answer (score 0):

hdfs is not a command anymore
use:

```
hadoop dfsadmin
```

Comment: when I use the hdfs user here is the result
[hdfs@MASTER ~]$ sudo hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
sudo: hadoop: command not found
when I use the root user here is the result
[root@MASTER ~]# hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
Safe mode is OFF
[root@MASTER ~]# hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
21/06/22 13:43:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Cannot create directory /user. Name node is in safe mode.

Comment: use: sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave

Comment: Hi Aref Khandan, Something is wrong, when I put the safe mode off and check the status I am told that it is on.
[root@MASTER ]# hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
21/06/23 08:24:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Safe mode is OFF
[root@MASTER]# hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get
21/06/23 08:24:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Safe mode is ON
[root@MASTER]#

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage is:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Result:Safe mode is OFF

For more information- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

Comment: Hi Shreya Sharma, when I use the hdfs user here is the result, 
[hdfs@Master ~]$ sudo hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
[sudo] password for hdfs:
sudo: hdfs: command not found.
when I use the root user here is the result
[root@MASTER ~]# hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
Safe mode is OFF
[root@MASTER~]# hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
21/06/22 13:43:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Cannot create directory /user. Name node is in safe mode